# Entity Framework reverting changes

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, revert

I am develloping a web form that has a wizard with 4 steps:

On each step I'me creating new entities generated from a database.

The problem is that being a wizzard, the user can change the properties of the controls that will originate the values to be stored.

So I need to release the created entity objects or return that entity values to the original rows stored on the database.

How can I do this.

Should'n it work if I set each created entity object to null?

By the way this is how I'm doing it:

```
entities = new Entities();

...

Client client = new Client();
client.name = tbxName.text

...

entities.SaveChanges();
entities.Connection.Close();
```

So If this code is executed on the 2nd wizard part of a wizard of 3 parts and I go back and fowrward through this set more the once the client creating runs more than once, so there's my problem.

So how can I unCreate it :-P

Thannks!!!

Answer (score 4):

If you are building wizard you must manage it as single operation. It means that you have to store built entity graph in the session and save it only if whole wizard is completed and confirmed. Your step logic also must check if related data are already present in the entity graph and use them instead of creating new one.

Comment: Thanks for the re+ly

An example would nice :-P

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull advice Yakimych... I've taken care of it right now

Comment: @RedEagle: And what kind of example do you expect?

Comment: Like I said, concerning the code above When I do:

Client client = new Client();
client.name = tbxName.text

That client is set on cache and when I do:

entities.SaveChanges();

That client is Inserted on the DB...

What I need is an example of how to undo this insert having the SaveChanges method invocation

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You must save changes only in the last step of your wizard when user confirms it. If you save anything during any other step it is just saved and you can only delete it from database. No revert exists.

Comment: +1, your approach is correct but I think RegEagle does not have idea about Context and it's lifetime, since context concept did not exist in earlier simple CRUD approach, people maintain their own context and it is difficult to explain them. People still deal with the IDs, I can understand RegEagle's concern as even I took little time to understand the context. Since you answered first, I didnt add my answer but you can add little explanation of context that will help RedEagle.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Entity Framework, why not implement the Unit Of Work pattern? Each part of your wizard builds the UoW and the "final step" commits the unit of work.

There was an article called "[The Unit Of Work Pattern And Persistence Ignorance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx)" in MSDN magazine a few years ago that explains the concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it:

1- Create a place where you can manage your Session variables :

```
public class SessionObjects { }
```

2- I save my ObjectContext in the Session so I create a property to manage it in the mentioned class :

```
public static ObjectContextEntities ObjectContextEntities
{
    get
    {
        return (ObjectContextEntities)HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectContextEntities"];
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectContextEntities"] = value;
    }

}
```

3- Initialize the ObjectContext on the wizard's start and dispose it on its end:

```
void StartWizard()
{
    SessionObject.ObjectContextEntities = new ObjectContextEntities(); 
}

void StartWizard()
{
    SessionObject.ObjectContextEntities = new ObjectContextEntities(); 
}

void EndWizard()
{
    ((ObjectContextEntities)SessionObject.ObjectContextEntities).Dispose();
}
```

4- To save wizard result to the database you can call:

```
void SaveWizard()
{
    ((ObjectContextEntities)SessionObject.ObjectContextEntities).SaveAllChanges();
}
```

5- To reset wizard simply call EndWizard then StartWizard .

I guess you know how to manage your ObjectEntity objects and in the ObjectContext so you can continue from here by your self ..